# Что означают параметры relax и timeout в методе start_pooling из библиотеки aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram

Бот выдавал такую ошибку `cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [network is unreachable]` и при изменении параметров увидел, что если **timeout=250, relax=0.5**, то перестает выдавать такую ошибку. Не нашел в документации информации о сути этих параметров.

Как я понял timeout - это время ожидания от сервера, а про relax догадок нет.
Так же находил в интернете способы исправить данную ошибку через изменение в библиотеке - данный способ не привел к изменению

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот в одном [иссью на гитхабе](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/issues/183) нашёл:

> `dispatcher.start_polling()` has a `relax` parameter, which regulates frequency of polling requests.

Судя и по названию, и по описанию, этот параметр задаёт **задержку между запросами**. Там ещё дальше упоминается, что она в секундах:

> However, there is no way to set it to something other then default 0.1 s.

Потом там было сделано изменение в коде, которое даёт доступ к этому параметру.

Ну а `timeout` везде одно и тоже означает - сколько максимум ждать ответа, чтобы ожидание не оказалось вечным.